# Let $G$ be a multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers, with homomorphism $\phi:G→G$ given by $\phi(z)=z^4$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers. Consider the group homomorphism from $\phi:G→G$ given by $\phi(z)=z^4$

a) identify $H$, the kernel of $\phi$

b) identify (upto isomorphism) the quotient space $G/H$

My attempt:

a) $H=\ker\phi=\{z\in G:\phi(z)=1\}$

i.e $\phi(z)=z^4=1$

i.e $(\cos x + i \sin x)^4=1$

i.e $\cos4x + i \sin4x=1$

i.e $\cos4x=1,\sin4x=0$

solving above equation we will get $z=e^{iπn/2}$
so $H=\{e^{in\pi/2},n\in \Bbb{N}\}$

Comment: Does $\pi \in \mathrm{Ker}(\phi)$, if you check it directly? Hint: you switched from $z$ to $x$, but you never switched back.

Comment: Minor quibble: saying G is *A* multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers isn't quite precise. There are many mutliplicative groups of non-zero complex numbers, all of which are subgroups of *The* multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers, namely $(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{ 0\},\times)$. For instance, $\{1,i,-1,-i\}$ is a set of non-zero complex numbers that forms *a* multiplicative group.

Comment: "**A** group of non-zero complex numbers" is a weird phrase. Do you really mean to allow $G$ to be any subgroup of $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, or do you want "**The** group of non-zero complex numbers?"

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that $G=(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\},\times)$. Then $\ker\varphi$ is, as you wrote, the set of those $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $z^4=1$. Therefore$$\ker\varphi=\{1,-1,i,-i\}.$$

The quotient space can be identified with $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ itself. That's because the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}G&\longrightarrow&G\\z&\mapsto&z^4\end{array}$$is a surjective group homomorphism, and therefore it induces a isomorphism between $G/H$ and $G$.

Comment: I highly doubt that this is the intended answer for (b). I assume they want the quotient group to be classified.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Probably. But let us see what the OP has to say about this.

Comment: The quotient space has no boundary points. An analogous statement would  be the quotient space $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ can be identified to $[0,1)$ and while there is a bijection between these things you lose all the structure.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Well, I decided to correct my answer befor any interference from the OP.

Comment: @PVAL-inactive What do you think now?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews There is no reference to Topology in the question and anyway the map that I defined is a homemorphism too, if we consider on $G/H$ the quotient topology.

Comment: "No reference to topology" other than the word "space," which is never used to talk about groups unless they are topological groups.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are talking about a question posted here by someone whe clearly is not fluent in English!